# Как засетапить Allure Testops для репозитория на Gradle + Cucumber

Tags: gradle, allure, cucumber

Исходные данные:

```
id "io.qameta.allure" version "2.11.0"
junitVersion = '4.13.2'
cucumberVersion = '7.8.0'
allureVersion = '2.19.0'
```

Получилось сбилдить локально и сгенерить репорт через  gradle allureServe

Как сделать так, чтобы автоматически генерился репорт в папке target и популился в Allure Testops?

Answer (score -1):

Хело!
Здесь это описано довольно подробно: https://docs.qameta.io/allure-testops/quickstart/upload/
Зависит от того, какой CI используется: будет или плагин для CI сервера или allurectl (см. тут: https://github.com/allure-framework/allurectl)

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: копировать доку?